# Read a sequence of numbers in a String

Tags: c, arrays, reverse

I have to make a program that receives a sequence of numbers, stores them in an (int)array and prints in reverse order. The input is composed of two lines: The first line contains an integer indicating the amount of integers and the second line contains integers separated by a blank space to be printed reverse order, like the following example:

Input:

4

2 5 45 10

Output:

10 45 5 2

The problem is that I can't store each integer in a different position of the array, since they are only separated by a blank space (instead of [ Enter ] ). How could I solve this problem?? (sorry for the English, it's not my native language).

Comment: I would like to see your piece of code first!!!

Comment: You do not need to store them in a different position. Simply read the array from back to front in the print method.

Comment: DV: For changing the title to match the selected answer, especially when an answered existed that met the original title and posts goals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`scanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) does the job:

```
  int max;
  scanf("%d", &max); 

  for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
  {
    int number;
    scanf("%d", &number); 
    printf("%d\n", number);
  }
```

This allows you to enter:

```
3
11 12 13
```

and you will get this output:

```
11
12
13
```

Storing the numbers in an array and displaying them in reverse order is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: OP wants output in reverse order.

Comment: @AnukulSangwan : yes, but his problem was accepting user input with spaces between numbers. I didn't want to do *all* the work at his place.

Comment: man it worked, I just stored the values instead of printing them. Thank you veeery much!

Comment: One downvote, and answer accepted... strange world.

Comment: This does not "stores them in an (int)array" as posted by OP.

Comment: @chux see the second comment.

Comment: Comments are ancillary to the posts title and content.  Concerning lack of an `int` array`: having " I didn't want to do all the work at his place" in the answer would have made sense.

Answer (score 3):

If the compiler supports Varaible Length Arrays then you can write something like the following

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ) 
{
    unsigned int n;

    if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) == 1 && n != 0 )
    {
        int a[n];
        unsigned int i = 0;

        while ( i < n && scanf( "%d", &a[i] ) == 1 ) i++;

        while ( i != 0 ) printf( "%d ", a[--i] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}
```

If to enter

```
4
2 5 45 10
```

then the program output is

```
10 45 5 2
```

Otherwise you should allocate the array dynamically after reading the first number.